# UTC time in database whose type is 'timestamp without timezone' to show in UTC in response

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, timezone, utc

I have a field in postgres whose type is "timestamp without timezone".
It is UTC time in database which I want to show in API response.

I used the following code to show it in same UTC timezone but it is adding my local time offset in API response-

```
// date from db in UTC is 2018-06-06 09:59:04.103
Date createdDateTime = description.getCreatedDateTime();
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try {
        Date date = isoFormat.parse(createdDateTime.toString());
        description.setCreatedDateTime(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.error("An exception has occured in parsing .", e);
        }
```

My creation time in IST- `2018-06-06 15:16:04.103 IST`
I am still getting the output with offset in response:
`Jun 6, 2018 8:46:52 PM`

I am using hibernate to fetch the data from table.

Comment: Can you use Java 8 stuff?

Comment: Yes I can use that too.

Comment: That’s great, My God. Hibernate should be able to transfer `LocalDateTime` objects to and from your database. Then you just need the UTC conversion, which `java.time` performs straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This column type should return a `Timestamp` type in Java (or a `LocalDateTime` with JDBC 4.2+). That timestamp will contain the original date, but in your default timezone. So you need to apply a UTC timezone to it.

```
java.sql.Timestamp t = ...;
ZonedDateTime zdt = t.toLocalDateTime() //remove time zone information
                     .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC); //this is actually a UTC time
```

At this point, you can keep using `java.time` objects (no reason not to if you can) or you can convert the `ZonedDateTime` to a `java.util.Date` with:

```
java.util.Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Comment: Once I used java 8, I got the correct response. But thanks for the answer which is what I used too.

Answer (score 4):

## `java.util.Date::toString` applies zone

You are likely being confused by the well-intentioned but unfortunate design decision of the `java.util.Date::toString` method to dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a String to represent the value of the `Date` which is actually always in UTC by definition. One of *many* reasons to avoid this terribly troublesome old class.

## Wrong data type in database

> I have a field in postgres whose type is "timestamp without timezone". It is UTC time in database which I want to show in API response.

This is a contradiction in terms. A SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` column does not hold a UTC value. That data type lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. (Such UTC values should have instead been stored in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.)

The values you inserted may have been *intended* for UTC, but you lost that fact once stored to the database.

## java.time

### Avoid `java.sql.Timestamp`

There is *no* need to be using `java.sql.Timestamp`. That legacy class should be avoided. As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* types with the database. [Hibernate supports *java.time*](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844).

### `LocalDateTime`

Lacking any zone/offset, you should retrieve those values using [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class. That class also lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

If you want to *assume* that retrieved value represents a moment in UTC, apply a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) to get a [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object. For UTC specifically, we can use the predefined constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

### Not `ZonedDateTime`

While the `ZonedDateTime` class will technically work here in place of the `OffsetDateTime` class, its use is inappropriate.

A time zone is much more than an offset. A zone is a history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a specific region. In contrast, an offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours and minutes, nothing more, nothing less.

So using a `ZonedDateTime` in this context of UTC is misleading and potentially confusing.

### `Instant`

Now, in your `OffsetDateTime` object, you have a moment in UTC.

If you know you want to work only in UTC from there, extract a `Instant`. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition. When representing moments in UTC, generally use `Instant`. If you need more flexibility such as in generating strings in various formats, switch to using `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).